# In C#, can null be used as a value or operand?

Tags: c#, null

The following C# code:

```cs
int? a = null;
Console.WriteLine(a ?? 3);
```

can print out `3`.  But if it is changed to:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(null ?? 3);
```

then it cannot run, giving out

```
error CS0019: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type '<null>' and 'int'
```

Is it possible to use `null` as a value or operand in C#?

Comment: From **MSDN** :  _IIn C# 7.3 and earlier, the type of the left-hand operand of the ?? operator must be either a reference type or a nullable value type. Beginning with C# 8.0, that requirement is replaced with the following: the type of the left-hand operand of the ?? and ??= operators cannot be a non-nullable value type. In particular, beginning with C# 8.0, you can use the null-coalescing operators with unconstrained type parameters:.,_ But you can cast the null to your own type and then use it `Console.WriteLine((null as int?) ?? 3);`

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
Console.WriteLine((int?)null ?? 3);
```

As `null` doesn't have a type, you need to cast it to the reference type or nullable type

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the type is given by the context. For example you can do:

```
(int?)null ?? 3
```

or

```
null ?? (int?)3
```

If you want boxing instead of wrapping to `Nullable<>`, that is:

```
(object)null ?? 3
```

or

```
null ?? (object)3
```

or you could use another base class or interface that an `int` implements, like:

```
(IFormattable)null ?? 3
```

or

```
null ?? (IFormattable)3
```

A naked `null` does not have a type in itself, but it is implicitly convertible to a bunch of types that allow a null value.

For a reference type, the type can be inferred from the context:

```
null ?? "three"  /* OK */
```